# Social network subscribe mechanism

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, ajax-load

Ребят кто может объяснить как работает система подписок, ну чтобы отображалось число а при клике отображать их имена.

Comment: Хранятся id всех кто подписался. Выводится количество таких записей, а при клике по ajax подтягиваются сами записи со всеми необходимыми данными

Comment: О спасибо большое очень помогли, простите а как правильнее хранить img данные?

Comment: Думаю в виде файлов на диске, что бы nginx мог их сам отдавать, это гораздо быстрее, чем скриптом читать из БД сами изображения. А в БД можно хранить например путь к файлу или какую нибудь другую информацию на основе которой можно построить url, который отдать клиенту, по которому он уже получит img